# C preprocessor variable constant?

Tags: c, assembly, c-preprocessor

I'm writing a program where a constant is needed but the value for the constant will be determined during run time.  I have an array of op codes from which I want to randomly select one and _emit it into the program's code. Here is an example:

```
unsigned char opcodes[] = { 
  0x60, // pushad
  0x61, // popad
  0x90  // nop
}

int random_byte = rand() % sizeof(opcodes);
__asm _emit opcodes[random_byte]; // optimal goal, but invalid
```

However, it seems _emit can only take a constant value. E.g, this is valid:

```
switch(random_byte) {
  case 2:
    __asm _emit 0x90
    break;
}
```

But this becomes unwieldy if the opcodes array grows to any considerable length, and also essentially eliminates the worth of the array since it would have to be expressed in a less attractive manner.

Is there any way to neatly code this to facilitate the growth of the opcodes array? I've tried other approaches like:

```
#define OP_0 0x60
#define OP_1 0x61
#define OP_2 0x90

#define DO_EMIT(n) __asm _emit OP_##n

// ...

unsigned char abyte = opcodes[random_byte];
DO_EMIT(abyte)
```

In this case, the translation comes out as OP_abyte, so it would need a call like DO_EMIT(2), which forces me back to the switch statement and enumerating every element in the array.

It is also quite possible that I have an entirely invalid approach here. Helpful feedback is appreciated.

Comment: BTW, `rand() % N` is usually pretty bad. http://www.c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  What is the value of having code that is random every time you run the compiler (but constant every time you run that one compiled program)?

Comment: I am writing a disassembler and want to address some anti-disassembly techniques. Therefore, I'm writing a counterpart that can inject anti-disassembly code blocks and wanted to make it as robust as possible; hence the need to use `_emit`. @caf: Thanks. I am using Visual C++; from what I've found thus far, `_emit` is the only way to drop a byte comparable to gcc's `.byte` or masm's `db`. The page permissions will not have changed, but good note on the cache :)

Comment: @Michael Jones: Sure, and `_emit` sounds like it should be perfectly useable - it doesn't matter that the byte emitted is a constant, because it's just a placeholder - it'll be overwritten at runtime.  The key part is giving the location of that emitted byte a name, so that you can reference it from C code.  That's what the label does in my example.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what compiler/assembler you are using, but you could do what you're after in GCC using a label.  At the `asm` site, you'd write it as:

```
asm (
    "target_opcode: \n"
    ".byte 0x90\n" );    /* Placeholder byte */
```

...and at the place where you want to modify that code, you'd use:

```
extern volatile unsigned char target_opcode[];
int random_byte = rand() % sizeof(opcodes);
target_opcode[0] = random_byte;
```

Perhaps you can translate this into your compiler's dialect of `asm`.

Note that all the usual caveats about self-modifying code apply: the code segment might not be writeable, and you may have to flush the I-cache before executing the modified code.

Comment: +1 for the caveats, which are definitely important to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do any randomness in the C preprocessor AFAIK. The closest you could get is generating the random value outside. For instance:

```
cpp -DRND_VAL=$RANDOM ...
```

(possibly with a modulus to maintain the value within a range), at least in UNIX-based systems. Then, you can use the definition value, that will be essentially random.

Comment: Thanks, that would be random per compile, at least which is more than I have now.  Was hoping to be able to _emit a random byte that would change throughout the program execution, but I like your idea.

Comment: Yes, but how would it efficiently be changed during program execution?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
char operation[4]; // is it really only 1 byte all the time?
operation[0] = random_whatever();
operation[1] = 0xC3; // RET
void (*func)() = &operation[0];
func();
```

Note that in this example you'd need to add a RET instruction to the buffer, so that in the end you end up at the right instruction after calling func().

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had considered using a function pointer to redirect execution, but was hoping to _emit the op code inline without having to insert additional instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `_emit` at runtime into your program code is kind of like compiling the program you're running while the program is running.

You should describe your end-goal rather than just your idea of using `_emit` at runtime- there might be abetter way to accomplish what you want.  Maybe you can write your opcodes to a regular data array and somehow make that bit of memory executable.  That might be a little tricky due to security considerations, but it can be done.